# Rest Non CRUD search

Tags: java, rest

I've a problem with a GET operation in a REST WS. We have a Front-end panel with several filters for searching customers. The panel contains these filters:

- Customer ID (Customer property)
- Customer Name  (Customer property)
- Account number (Account property)
- License plate (Vehicle property)
  ...

In the domain model we have 3 entities:

- Customer
- Account (A customer could have 1 or more accounts)
- Vehicle (An account could have 1 or more vehicles)

How can I implement REST GET operation for this seach?

GET ..../customers/?name={name}&accountNum={accountNumber}&licensePlate={licensePlate}    ?????

I think it is wrong because accountNumber and licensePlate don´t belong to customer resource. I don´t need these properties in the result expected.

I think about create new resource like customerFilter but It is no sense if I have to return a customer resource.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. It's just a query parameter.

Comment: If you are not tied to the GET action - you can use POST to send a request object with the specific details of what you are requesting for and return. If not - a GET call is fine with query parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It will not pretend to be a specific answer for your question. But I think it will clarify something related to GET method.

According with [URI Specification - RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) and [Http Specification - RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), there are 3 kinds of ways to send data from client to server: via **query**, via **path** or via **message-body**.

When you are using GET method, it is not recommended to use message-body, because GET method can be cached for improving performance stuffs and these caches could ignore the message-body or reject the request:

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

So, you can choose now **query** or **path**. Both are in URL in this format:

`http://example.com/{path1}/{path2}?query1=value1&query2=value2`

What are the differences between these? according with [RFC 3986 - Path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) and [RFC 3986 - Query](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4):

> The path component contains data, usually organized in hierarchical
> form, that, along with data in the non-hierarchical query component
> (Section 3.4), serves to identify a resource within the scope of the
> URI's scheme and naming authority (if any).

> The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with
> data in the path component (Section 3.3), serves to identify a
> resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority
> (if any).

As conclusion, you can design whatever you want. You can use for example:

`GET .../customers?name={name}&accountNum={accountNumber}&licensePlate={licensePlate}`

`GET .../customers/{customerId}/`

`GET .../customers?customerId=12345`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with the url you have but your concern is also valid.

There is something that we need to take into consideration in this scenario. With this search what you expect to get as the response of the API call?

If you want response should contain information about customer only,  when the search condition gets satisfied then **/customer** is right.

If you want some generic response consisting of Customer, Account and Vehicle info, you can have some generic terminology instead of customer in the url.

I hope this will help you.
Thanks :)